# Linear space prove

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Check, what, set of all vectors parallel to the straight line $y=2x-3$ will be linear space.

Should I take one of the vectors and compare it with properties of linear space?

Comment: A linear subspace must contain $0$, therefore the required set must be a line parallel to this one that passes through the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check the three properties for a linear subspace $W$ on a field $\mathbb{K}$:

1. $0 \in W$
2. $w_1 \in W, w_2 \in W \implies w_1+w_2 \in W$
3. $w_1 \in W, c \in \mathbb{K} \implies cw_1\in W$

thus all the vectors parallel to the straight line are in the form $$(t,2t)$$ with t $\in\mathbb{R}$